# A collection of LaTeX equations?

Tags: database

I saw a web-site someday -- it had lots of codes for formulas from many fields of knowledge -- all categorized and searchable. So that when You teach, say, electrodynamics You could come there and get the code for Maxwell equations right away. I lost the linke and can't find the web-site any more.

Do You happen to know some sites like that?

**Edit**:

summary of solutions:

- http://www.equationsheet.com/
- Go to wikipedia, find the equation, copy its image as text with Ctrl-c -- and LaTeX code of image gets into the clipboard.

Comment: That's either Wikipedia and right click or Springer's LaTeX search. http://latexsearch.com/

Comment: There is collection of functions on http://functions.wolfram.com/ from there, you can obtain the `mathml` form for any function (among other forms) and convert that to latex using some tools I saw on the net (may be using xslt or such, or easier, if you have mathematica, copy the input text shown there next to the mathml for the function, paste it into Mathematica and type TexForm[...] on it. That will give the Latex code for that function. It says about the site `Already the largest formula compendium for mathematical functions on the web` But this is for functions, not equations.

Comment: Browser history couldn't help?

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke: It was a long time ago. A year or something like that. So not a chance.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is a (La)TeX question. Isn't it about finding a specific website or am I missing something?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: this might be true. Still who else will know the answer to this question, but the latex community?

Comment: @percusse -- warning about latexsearch: the code is not always "clean"; it obviously has not been edited for consistency and optimal appearance.  in addition, some of the symbols in the latex code are not shown in the output (i saw two instances of upright greek caps -- `\Uppsi` and `\Updelta` -- omitted in the responses from a random search using one of the suggested search examples).  while this might get one started, the output should always be reviewed for well-sized matching delimiters, proper spacing and alignment, etc.

Comment: @Adobe Perhaps consider a different user name: in general, names which might confuse people ('TeX' and 'MikeTeX' come to mind) tend to be discouraged.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Fully agree. Actually, I don't touch such automated code at all. However, if there is a complicated matrix or an array it's handy to copy paste the content and leave the syntax out.

Comment: @JosephWright: I picked the name long time ago, when I came to stackoverflow to study emacs. Even before I've been using TeX at all. I used to read a lot books back then, and Adobe alludes to those times -- because Adobe had strond association with "reader" for me. Stil if You insist I'll change it -- for the great respect to Your work.

Comment: @Adobe I don't insist: it's more that things can get a bit confusing if names looks like names of software, etc.

Comment: @JosephWright: that has an additional downside for I prefer open source.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe you mean [Equations sheet](http://www.equationsheet.com/)? ([Example](http://www.equationsheet.com/eqninfo/Equation-0210.html) of LaTeX code)

Comment: That's cool. The web-site seems like a fork of the link I posted.

Comment: @Adobe which link?

Comment: [Here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119696/8992)

Comment: uh, for some reason I didn't see your answer

Comment: In the "fork" you can also login (no idea why you should do that, but I assume it's a feature :P)

Comment: I just did it -- it allows You to collect You favorite equtions and have a quick access to them ever since. It's sad there's no way to add an equation, or customize the view of the site.

Answer (score 7):

Today I've been re-reading my LaTeX notes and I fount the link there: http://equplus.net

The web-site is [made by a girl and a cat](http://equplus.net/about.html).

Comment: @mozartstraße: this web-site is a good start. I'd say a larger collection is due. I think I'd start collect formulas I type. An on-line wiki resource dedicated to latex codes of formulas categorized by field would be great.

Answer (score 4):

Even if you're not logged into Wikipedia, you can go to Edit Page and have the MathML/LaTeX markup code for any equations on that page.

Comment: View image info on the equation image also can provide a `LaTeX` code in associated text.

Comment: Even greater: if You just copy the image of equation in Your browser as text (select it and press Ctrl-c) -- the latex code of image gets into a clipboard.

Answer (score 3):

for example two sources:

- http://mathworld.wolfram.com/letters/
- http://johanw.home.xs4all.nl/#formularium ([PDF](http://johanw.home.xs4all.nl/physics-hyperref.pdf))

Comment: The second is cool.

Comment: I just realized that Wolfram changed the behaviour of their formulars. In former times they used the alt field for the LaTeX code of all formulas ... :-(

Answer (score 0):

Check this link, contains many commands http://www.ntg.nl/doc/biemesderfer/ltxcrib.pdf

Comment: That't cool cheatsheet, but I was asking for latex codes of complete equations.

Answer (score 0):

Another great resource: http://www.mathtran.org

It's searchable and viewable without registration.